# Java import class System

Tags: java, class, import

I have a question on class imports, It seems you can call a method with a reduced line if you have imported the class. I don't understand what is the name of this operation, and how is it possible...

For instance :

Why this code

```
public class test 
{
        public static void main  (String args[])
        {
                System.out.print("Test");
        }
}
```

Can be replaced by

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class test 
{
        public static void main  (String args[])
        {
                out.print("Test");
        }
}
```

What happens if you have also an object named "out" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They are called static import (Obvious from the statement ;) ). Sun does not recommend the systematic use of static import for code clarity http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: Thanks, I should be more attentive :D . Does it exists in other languages too ?

Comment: Yes, there are other languages that have similar concepts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What happens is that out from external class must be referenced by full name:

```
String out = "Hello World";
java.lang.System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: No, `System.out.println(out);` will do in this case.

Answer (score 7):

The variable out will shadow the static import and you will have to use the full name in order to use the function print.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Tester5 {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    int out=0;
    out.print("Test");
  }
}
```

yields "cannot invoked print(String) on primitive type int. The same error is shown if out is an object.